# UIPickerController crashes the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a UIPickerController that gets your pictures and allows you to pick some of them though at the moment when I click the button to activate it the app crashes.

Here is the code that I am using for it:

in my `ViewDidLoad` method:

```
pickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
pickerController.allowsEditing = NO;
pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
```

The function:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    patientPicture = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    UIImageView *pictureView = (UIImageView *)[imageCell viewWithTag:777];
    pictureView.image = patientPicture;
    [_imgViewAdd reloadInputViews];
}
```

And it being called:

```
- (IBAction)addPicture:(id)sender {
    [self presentViewController:pickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

It is wierd because I have recently changed my app to Ipad only though while it was in IPhone it worked fine. When you click the button in NSLog this error message crops up which I supose is something to do with it:

```
UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent is not available on this device.
```

I suspect this is quite a common issue that people have

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try presenting in a popover...

```
pickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
UIPopoverController *popOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:pickerController];
popOverController.delegate = self;
```

and to present...

```
 [popOverController presentPopoverFromRect:yourframe inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Comment: I am not using frames though

Comment: What do I put as yourFrame